# Was told by management that there are concerns that will be addressed weeks from now

Tags: management, new-job, feedback

A bit of a follow up to [Should I follow up with things that aren't my fault, or forget them? Example: was told I was late for shift I didn't know about](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/167918/should-i-follow-up-with-things-that-arent-my-fault-or-forget-them-example-wa/167921#167921)

Where I work we become union after 250 hours, and effectively that is also the end of the probationary period. At work today I asked a manager how many hours I had eccumulated. She said about 100 but management needs to have a talk with me when I get close to 250 because there's been some concerns. I asked what type of concerns and she said I did not show up for a shift the other day (see linked questions). I told her that I wasn't informed I had one and had checked my call history for the day prior to the shift. She said she thought she had called me on another day, other than the one the day prior. Should I follow up further? I got the sense there were more "concerns" than just this one thing, though I may be paranoid.

Would it be reasonably for me to suggest having the discussion sooner so that any issues can be corrected? Should I schedule a meeting with management or just ask if there's any concerns next time I see them and they don't look too busy? I feel like I'm doing well in this job but also noticed I haven't been getting much feedback.

Comment: She doesn't want to tell you exactly what the "concerns" are because she really doesn't want you to correct them or otherwise deal with them. She wants to wait until you're at 250 hours, then use the "concerns" to torpedo your employment before you come under protection of the union.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri agreed, hence the question

Comment: In 100 hours you made something to be "concern" about. Yet they don't want you to fix it in next 150 hours. You should push for a meeting now. It will help you make better decision if you want to stay with this company.

Comment: Not big enough for it's own question but has been on my mind: the manager "tipped me" that I should transfer to another store because they have more hours. She said "you didn't hear it from me". This makes me feel strange that my manager wants to get rid of me but is OK with me still being in the company. Presumably this means she's willing to give me a good reference.

Comment: @Hedgehound Or they just want you out of mind and out of sight. If the other store fires you they can just point at that other store and at you, since you were the one that took action (and transferred, thus weakening your position) and not them.

Comment: @Hedgehound, Thanks for just accepting my answer. But I'm curious. Care to share an update on what happened. The transfer to another store bit does sound like your manager tried to save your job, and that a layoff was indeed highly likely after the Christmas & returns season was done for your store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would it be reasonably for me to suggest having the discussion sooner
> so that any issues can be corrected?

Yes, it would be reasonable. And no, you're not being paranoid.

But I would make this request over email if I were you. First, send the email, then make the request in person. This memorializes your request. If you don't have your boss's email address, you should send a text.

Your request needs to be two-pronged. First, it needs to address this unexcused no-show no-call absence (which is very serious). And second, your request needs to uncover any of the other concerns she may have hinted at. Because if you don't know what those other concerns are, there is really no way for you to take any kind of corrective action in the meantime otherwise.

Which begs the question, why wait a couple of weeks before correcting your behavior? This makes no sense unless her plan is to fire you.

> I told her that I wasn't informed I had one and had checked my call
> history for the day prior to the shift.

Call history can be altered. You just need to long-press on a logged phone number for it to disappear.

If your cell phone provider can provide of a log of incoming phone calls, I'd suggest you order a paper copy from them.

> She said she thought she had
> called me on another day, other than the one the day prior. Should I
> follow up further?

Clearly, you should.

If you don't, they may make their decision of not keeping you at the very last minute when you're at 249 hours, and then, they may not have time to talk to you to get your side of the story.

Also, if the industry of your employer is tied to the Christmas shopping season, keep in mind that you have the most leverage right now, just before Christmas. If you wait when they're less busy to talk to them, that's the time they may be looking to trim their workforce (especially their workforce which is still on probation and which doesn't have union representation yet).

Furthermore, every day this discussion gets delayed. Everyone's memory will get fuzzier and fuzzier.

And last but not least, if your reputation is tarnished now, and word spreads around your employer, the more time you wait, the more difficult it will be to get those allegations recanted by your manager and get your reputation repaired. Because by then, it will be the reputation of your manager which will be on the line.

Answer (score 3):

Check with your union to see if you can join now, without waiting until you have accumulated 250 hours.

Check directly with a representative of the union -- not with your supervisor or co-workers. The 250 hour requirement may be only a convenient tradition and not part of the union contract.

If the union feels that they are already in an adversarial relationship with management, they may be happy to find another case to prosecute. It gives them the opportunity to advertise, to non-members as well as members,  the kind of protection they offer.

Comment: Thanks I will do this. Not sure how to contact the union but I will ask some coworkers I trust.

Answer (score 2):

This is your boss giving you 4 weeks (more or less, assuming 40 hour work week) notice to find a new job, and you should be taking it as such.

There is no reason for your boss to not raise these issues immediately and ask you to rectify them, if indeed your boss wants you to rectify them and get a good review to keep you on staff after your probation.  If that was actually the case, your boss would call you into a meeting, lie out all the issues you're having, and proceed to describe actionable, measurable, "[SMART](https://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/smart-goals.htm)" steps that you can achieve to pass your probation.  Failing to do that is your manager telling you they want to:

1. Hide the information from you, so that you have no time to rectify your behaviour.
2. Allow you the least amount of time to prepare a defense of yourself from the charges to be levied against you when you are eventually fired (if such a defense is relevant, which it probably isn't).
3. Keep you working there for as long as possible to get their work done without any promise of keeping you any longer than they have to (249 hours).

**GET.  OUT.  NOW**.  You have no future in this company; they're signalling to you that they're going to fire you before your probation is up, and also that they have no interest in allowing you the opportunity to try to change their mind.  Start job hunting for a new job immediately.

Comment: I think it's jumping to conclusion taking "we need to have a talk" as 4 weeks notice

Comment: There's something to be said for going back and taking a look at answers vs what actually happened afterwards.  In this case, Ertai, you were the one that nailed it.